# ICMP "ping" not working on my EC2 instance, how to fix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can ping google.com from my PC, however I cannot ping my EC2 instance which has a static IP address.

I have setup the following in the security group - what else do I need?

```
Type
Protocol
Port range
Source
Description - optional
Custom ICMP - IPv4  Echo Reply  -   0.0.0.0/0   -
Custom ICMP - IPv4  Echo Reply  -   ::/0    -
SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   -
Custom ICMP - IPv6  IPv6 ICMP   All 0.0.0.0/0   -
Custom ICMP - IPv6  IPv6 ICMP   All ::/0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `Echo Request` as a protocol, not `Echo Reply`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Custom ICMP" / "Echo Reply" I needed "All ICMP" / "All"